# How to get from Rome Ciampino to Lido di Ostia?

Tags: airport-transfer, italy, cia

How to get from Rome Ciampino Airport (CIA) to [Lido di Ostia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostia_%28Rome%29) by public transport? Are there any direct buses / trains? How much would a ticket cost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no direct connection that I'm aware of.

Your best bet is:

- From Ciampino to Roma Termini (train station) using the [Schiaffini bus](http://www.schiaffini.com/ciampino/ciampino-fs-aeroporto-stazione-termini). The bus ticket is 3.90 Euros.
- From Roma Termini take the metro B line to Piramide stop
- From Piramide (aka Porto San Paolo) take the [Roma - Ostia Lido train](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome%E2%80%93Lido_railway)

Comment: Of course. Because all roads lead to Rome.