# Airport transfer from Ciampino to Termini

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, rome, cia

I found in [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/31193/30342) that is possible to go from Ciampino airport to Termini.

The solution suggests [this bus](http://www.schiaffini.com/ciampino/ciampino-fs-aeroporto-stazione-termini).

I read that it is possible to take a bus to Casabianca and then take a train to Termini.

Is this possible? Is it much more cheaper?

People with experience, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you have two (three) options:

- The [Rome Airport Bus](http://www.romeairportbus.com/) that connects Ciampino to Termini (the main train station)
- [Terravision](http://www.terravision.eu/) which is another private airport shuttle that connects the airports passing by the center and Termini
- The taxi (the most expensive but faster option)

Living in Rome, I have never tried one of this options. But I've seen Terravision buses quite frequently.

About Casabianca, that's a local train station outside Rome. I'm not sure where you found it, but it definitely doesn't seem to be a good choice to me. The line (Velletri-Roma) is a very low-traffic and low-quality train line, it's better to take a bus shuttle from Ciampino to Termini.

Comment: Casabianca was suggested by Google maps. Thanks for informing about the bus.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Simone Carletti's answer, there is also the "Bus Shuttle" operating between Ciampino Airport and Termini (see 
http://www.sitbusshuttle.com/en/ciampino/). It operates as a competitor to Terravision on that route.

In Ciampino airport, their ticket booth is adjacent to the one of TerraVision. Since you are asking for recommendations, I would suggest to buy a ticket to Termini from one of these booths, for whatever bus is the next one. With a ticket price of 4 Euros (one way) for any of the options, splitting up the trip into a bus and a train part is likely to be not worth the hassle.

For the trip back, you need to buy a ticket ahead of time (e.g., on TerraVision's website). Otherwise you will pay the walk-up fare of 6 Euros. You will also pay this fare if you do not visit the ticket booths at Ciampino airport, but rather walk to the bus straight.

Comment: Thanks. But, please, could you explain again that part about *buy a ticket ahead of time*? Can I buy both tickets (Ciampino-Termini and Termini-Ciampino) when I arrive at Ciampinho airport in those booths you said? In this case, I would pay 8 euros? I didn't understand that part about *walk-up fare*.

Comment: @Sigur I actually don't know if you can buy both at the same time. You can definitely buy Terravision bus trips online. But the tickets you buy online will be *for a specific time* - that is useful for the return trip to the airport, but a bit less useful on the way to Termini, as your plane may have a delay. By walk-up-fare, I meant what you pay when just turning up at the bus and buying a ticket immediately before entering the bus. That is a bit more expensive.